# PThreads for visual studio express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++, parallel-processing, pthreads, visual-c++-2010

Recently i started learning parallel programming using PThreads , but i have a problem with the compilation "**how to include the library into visual studio**" , please any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Pthreads are supported natively on Visual C++. You could try and use [Pthreads-Win32](http://sources.redhat.com/pthreads-win32/index.html)